# Extract Data from a webservice with Python

Tags: python, rest, web-services

I requested the access to a web service to retrieve data from an online database using Python.
Data are arrays of numbers.

They gave me these two things :

```
<DailyReport xmlns="http://...">
<DataFilter>
<Header>
<LineCode>{{LINE_CODE}}</LineCode>
<StartDate>2019-08-20 00:00:00</StartDate>
<EndDate>2019-08-30 00:00:00</EndDate>
<WoType>Standard</WoType>
</Header>
<ViewsType>
<View>WorkAction</View>
<View>Event</View>
<View>Movement</View>
<View>Stop</View>
<View>Stock</View>
<View>Shift Log</View>
<View>WorkingHours</View>
<View>numberOfCoffee</View>
</ViewsType>
</DataFilter>
</DailyReport>
```

`Services/Rapport/DMRSVC.svc/DMRRESTService/GetDMRView`

My problem is that no one can tell me what is it or how to use it.
Note that I hid the url and the variable names between  and

For example by doing that :

```
import requests
url = "http://..."
reponse = requests.get(url)
print(reponse)
```

The error :

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='...', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: ... (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FED1801E08>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu'))
```

I also tried to manipulate the "header" in the request.get method but with no result.
I dont really know what to do.

Comment: The connection is being refused, try a proxy or changing the user agent.

Comment: The problem is happening in making the connection, so modifying your request won't help anything. You should check you are using the right URL and port and that you don't have a firewall or such blocking the connection.